# How to access data elements in GraphQL object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, aws-amplify, graphql-js

I have a promise that yields a GraphQL object.  It appears I should be able to access the contents via a `data` field. That doesn't work (see below). How should I be accessing the contents of the object?

Here is the code. (I have indicated below which one logs correctly and which does not):

```
export async function getModel() {
    try {
        const router = useRouter()
        const {id} = router.query
        console.log("id=" + id)
        return await API.graphql(
            {
                query: queries.getYawaraModel,
                variables: {id: id}
            }
        )
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("my error:" + e)
    }
}

export default function Detail({props}) {
    try {
        getModel()
            .then(function (v) {
                    console.log(v)      //<- object prints
                    console.log(v.data) //<- data is undefined?
                }
            )
            .catch(function (v) {
                    console.log("error v:" + v)
                }
            )
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("detail error" + e)
    }
}
```

Here are the results in the Chrome Dev Tools console log:
[image]

So, what is the correct way to access the contents inside the object?

Comment: I believe you have something wrong on your query, can you share it? Also you dont tell which framework are you using to make the graphql requests. I use graphql-request, and it always returns the data inside the operation name,  maybe you can try `v.getYawaraModel`